# Best way to handle collaborative projects w/ respect to ETH wallets

Tags: wallets, nft, dao

I'm a generative NFT coder being approached by various teams to collab on NFT projects. Here's what I'm wondering, specifically:  On OpenSea, I can set a single payment wallet address for NFT sales.  Is there a way that I can get a wallet address from a service that could then auto-pay all collaborators at their own private wallet addresses? (I assume a DAO could do this, maybe?, or perhaps a multi-sig wallet?, or is there something else anyone would recommend to easily manage such a thing?) Just wondering how to best handle collaboration with, essentially, strangers, and also in this scenario (OpenSea) where we have a single payment address option only.